# Grouping to obtain specific average values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to group pivot table elements in order to achieve certain average values for each group? For example, I might want 5 groups with averages 3,5,8,13.

Comment: Are you wanting to define ranges (upper and lower bounds) so that your data points within those ranges have averages 3, 5, 8, and 13?

Comment: @Excellll Yes that would work, either setting ranges to get the averages or just setting the average values I want directly.

Comment: I don't think this is something you would do with a pivot table. You could show the result in a pivot table, but all the work would be done on the input data, either manually or using Solver.